# WCF Service: behavior with serviceCredentials with certificate - how should I configure it for Azure?

Tags: wcf, security, azure, certificate

I have simple WCF Service `Service1` with the following config:

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SecuredBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceCredentials type="System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceCredentials">
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WCFS.Service1,WCFS"/>
        <serviceCertificate findValue="BasicWCFCert" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />
        <windowsAuthentication includeWindowsGroups="false"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SecuredWsHttpBinding">
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="WCFS.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="SecuredBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SecuredWsHttpBinding"
      name="End1" contract="WCFS.IService1" />
  </service>
</services>
```

So on my development machine I'm using this service with certificate "BasicWCFCert" stored in LocalMachine in "My" (Personal) location.

How should I change it before publishing this service in Azure?
How can I tell Service1 to use one of certificates uploaded to Azure?

Comment: Please specify if you're using a Cloud Service or a Web Site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried attaching the cert in the role configuration screen as show below?

You can get the thumbprint by running `certmgr.msc` and going to the relevant certificate.

[image]

Comment: I didn't think about this part this way (only about certs for web roles). I'll try, thanks.